# Support of convolution of Borel probability measures over complete metrizable TVS (paper about Prevalence)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I've been studying the paper ["Prevalence: a translation-invariant "almost every" on infinite-dimensional spaces" by Hunt, Sauer & Yorke](http://yorke.umd.edu/Yorke_papers_most_cited_and_post2000/1992_12_Hunt_Sauer_Bull-AMS_Prevalence.pdf), and I'm trying prove that the support of the convolution of measures (that can be assumed to be finite or probability measures) is contained in the sum  of their support (footnote on page 223) without luck so far. The best my research has come up was a similar question made here: [Support of the convolution of two measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834018/support-of-the-convolution-of-two-measures), but no  hint on how to prove it was given.

For the problem, let $V$ a complete metrizable TVS (not necessarily separable), consider $\mu$ and $\nu$ probability Borel measures n $V.$ The convolution of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is
$$\mu * \nu(S) = \int_{V} \nu(S - x) \, d\mu(x) = \int_{V} \mu(S - y) \, d\nu(y),$$
for $S \subseteq V$ a Borel set. I want to show
$supp \ \mu * \nu \subseteq supp \ \mu + supp \  \nu.$

The only thing I can think of to a approach this problem is to somehow imitate the proof for the analogous statement on the support of convolution of functions (e.g. [What will be the support of the convolution of two test functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395100/what-will-be-the-support-of-the-convolution-of-two-test-functions)), but it hardly seems to work without some extra assumptions on our measures. To start, the [wikipedia on support of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)) (also the definition of support I'm using) claims for example that $$\int_X f \, d\mu = \int_{supp\ \mu} f \, d\mu$$
if $\mu$ is a Radon measure, and the paper is not assuming inner regularity.

Any hints on how to solve this is very appreciate, thanks.

Comment: A finite Borel measure on a compact metrizable space (or, more generally, and Polish space) is automatically inner regular.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, could you elaborate?  I don't see how this would apply here, since the spaces are not compact. I thought about Polish spaces but the paper doesn't assume separability, otherwise yes, Borel probability measures would be inner regular.

Comment: Fact 2 in the paper states "Every shy Borel set S has a transverse measure which is finite with compact support." Compact supports are explicitly assumed right before Definition 3 is introduced. The argument uses compactness.

Comment: I see now, thank you. With this I was able to prove inner regularity for the measures arising from fact 2.